# How can we identify tampered byte[] in C# AES decryption

Tags: c#, encryption, cryptography, aes

We have implemented **AES encryption** in our project. And it works fine.

But, if the user **tampers the byte[]** then the Decrypt function returns a wrong plain text with different symbols like � in it.

We want to handle this case by determining that the data is tampered.

Please find below the code of Decrypt function:

```
public static string Decrypt(string encryptedText)
        {
            try
            {     
               // First convert the base64 string to byte[].
                var cipherText = Convert.FromBase64String(encryptedText);                
                if (cipherText == null || cipherText.Length <= 0)
                    throw new ArgumentNullException("cipherText");            

                string plaintext = null;

                // Create an Aes object                
                using (Aes aesAlg = Aes.Create())
                {
                    aesAlg.Key = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("abc");
                    aesAlg.IV = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("xyz");

                    // Create a decryptor to perform the stream transform.
                    ICryptoTransform decryptor = aesAlg.CreateDecryptor(aesAlg.Key, aesAlg.IV);
                    
                    using (MemoryStream msDecrypt = new MemoryStream(cipherText))
                    {
                        using (CryptoStream csDecrypt = new CryptoStream(msDecrypt, decryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Read))
                        {
                            using (StreamReader srDecrypt = new StreamReader(csDecrypt))
                            {
                                // Read the decrypted bytes from the decrypting stream                                
                                plaintext = srDecrypt.ReadToEnd();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                return plaintext;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return null;
            }
        }
```

Please help me to solve my issue.

Thanks!

Comment: unless you know how to determine a "good" decrypted string from a "bad" one, there's no way. that, however, could be achieved by including a checksum. which is the standard way to go for this kind of problems since basically forever

Comment: As Franz says, create a checksum. Something like a CRC16 hash ought to be suitable for this.

Comment: Thanks @FranzGleichmann .As I am new to AES encryption can you please let me know where and how to use the checksum?

Comment: the checksum has absolutely nothing to do with any encryption - but with the data you are encrypting. how you implement this, you would best know yourself. especially since the "best" way to add a checksum is completely dependent on your use case. also, keep in mind: the user could simply tamper with the original data, _before_ it is encrypted, including a manipulated checksum.

Comment: [`AesGcm`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.aesgcm?view=net-5.0) would give you a *cryptographically secure* means of authenticating the content.

Comment: This is typically achieved with a [MAC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message_authentication_code) (message authentication code) that is generated based on the ciphertext ([encrypt-then-MAC](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/202)). The MAC resembles a checksum that is protected against modification with a key. There are also modes that already do this implicitly, e.g. [GCM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galois/Counter_Mode), s. Damien_The_Unbeliever's comment.

Comment: I would recommend a mode which offers an "authenticated encryption", you can do this with AES, an example in DotNet would be [AES-GCM](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.aesgcm?view=net-5.0).